# oauth2 client_secret from my gmail account?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-oauth

When I use https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground to find out what my client id and client secret is of my own gmail account I get

```
client_secret=************&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=...&client_id=...
```

Where can i find my client_secret `***` that I can use with the refresh token to generate new access tokens?

I need it for in app billing v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what what Client Id and Client Secret are. They refer to the application client, not the user. So for example when using Oauth Playground, Oauth Playground *is* the client, which is why Google blanks them out so you can't create an app which impersonates Oauth Client.

Assuming you're writing an app that uses Google APIs, then you need to register that app in the Cloud Console. As part of that process, the Cloud Console will generate a random client id and secret, which you will then use in your app during the OAuth process.